# how have two parent div next to each other

Tags: css, html, position

I'm working on a css/html site and I have this problem: in my style.css I got two divs, one for sidebar and one for content. I would like the sidebar to be, well, at the side, but when both are present the content always goes below the sidebar, unless I put that in position:absolute. In that case I have a problem when small screens are used, 'cause they get one over the other.

I paste the code, hope you can help!

```
/* This is for content */
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

#modal {    
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block; 
    display: table; 
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: 25px auto;
    text align: center;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    overflow: auto;
}

#modal header {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #888;
    padding: 10px;
}

#modal h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;
    color: #323232;
    text-align: center;
}

#modal section {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 175%;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}
```

while this is the sidebar

```
/*sidebar */
#sidebar{
    position: static;
    margin-top: 15px;
    max-width: 150px;
}

#sidebar ul,
#sidebar ul li,
#sidebar ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    top: 5%;
}

#sidebar ul {
    position: static;
    top: 90px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    min-height: 1px;
    line-height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#sidebar ul li.hover,
#sidebar ul li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
}

#sidebar ul ul {
    margin-top: 1px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 99%;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar ul ul li {
    float: none;
}

#sidebar ul ul ul {
    top: 1px;
    left: 99%;
}

#sidebar ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    float: none;
}

#sidebar ul ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* Custom CSS Styles */
#sidebar {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 180px;
}

#sidebar ul a,
#sidebar ul a:link,
#sidebar ul a:visited {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#sidebar > ul {
    float: none;
}

#sidebar ul {
    background: #a0a0a0;
}

#sidebar > ul > li {
    border-left: 3px solid #000000;
}

#sidebar > ul > li > a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#sidebar > ul > li:hover {
    border-left: 3px solid #9b1a1c;
}

#sidebar ul li:hover > a {
    color: #9b1a1c;
}

#sidebar > ul > li:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

/* Sub Menu */
#sidebar ul ul a:link,
#sidebar ul ul a:visited {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#sidebar ul ul {
    width: 180px;
    background: none;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}

#sidebar ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

#sidebar ul ul li {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul ul li:last-child > a {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#sidebar ul ul li:first-child:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 13px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, arimane. However, without the markup, it is extremely hard for us to diagnose your problem. Perhaps you can recreate your problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), with your markup and CSS?

Comment: If your content div width is 100% of the viewport if make sense that there is no room for the sidebar to be aside. It works if you position it absolute since you make the sidebar _overlap_ the content div, which is not the same as being aside.

Comment: use float :left to sidebar and right to content or give ur jsfiddle link

Comment: Thanks guys, here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zQew/3/
Don't know why looks so strange on JSFiddle, with the content over the main menu and such, on FF and Chrome looks good